# Dynamic form content change in symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I have 3 entities that I want to use in a form, User, Address and Tag. The tag references both user and address via their ids:

```
mysql> describe user;
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | longtext | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe address;
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | longtext | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe tag;
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id    | int(11)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| address_id | int(11)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| text       | longtext | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

My form builder:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('user',EntityType::class, [
            'class' => User::class
        ])
        ->add('address', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Address::class
        ])
        ->add('text')
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
    ;
}
```

Now, I added some JS so that the form is submitted when the user changes either the selected User or Address from the dropdowns. But, if a corresponding tag exists with the selected user and address, I want to pre-populate the text field in the form so the user can edit it. Does anyone know how I can do this in symfony?

[Please check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQxGW.png)

On change, submit the form with JS. If a tag exists in the DB with the corresponding User and Address, preload the text from DB in the text field so the user can see it's already existing and it can be edited. Otherwise just display the empty box and a new tag will be created when Save is pressed.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow, please take a look at Symfony form events. It explains what you want to do
https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to bind your form to your tag class. So in TagType.php you will have:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Tag::class,
        'csrf_token_id' => 'tag_form'
    ]);
}
```

There are many ways to implement the functionality you want. You could for example, find all Tags in your database, list them, and through edit buttons, edit each tag you want. Then you would just have also a create button to create new tags.

But in the way you chose to implement it, you don't really have to submit a form when changing the user or the address. All you need is to create a javascript function like this:

```
function onChange(){
    var userId = $('input#user_input').val();
    var addressId = $('input#address_input').val();
    $.post( "check-tag", { user: userId, address: addressId }).done(function( data ) {
        if (data.tagText !== ""){
            $( "input#text_input" ).val( data.tagText );
        }
    });
}
```

Then bind your event handlers like this:

```
$('input#user_input, input#address_input').on('change', function() {
    onChange();
});
```

Your controller for the 'check-tag' route should look like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/check-tag", name="check-tag", options={ "expose" = true })
 */
public function checkTag(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em) {
    $userId = $request->request->get('user');
    $addressId = $request->request->get('address');
    $tagRepository = $em->getRepository(Tag::class);
    $tag = $tagRepository->findBy(['user' => $userId, 'address' => $addressId]);

    $tagText = $tag ? $tag->getText() : '';

    return $this->json(['tagText' => $tagText]);
}
```

Finally you can submit properly your form when you are ready to. No need for validation etc when you just need to check if a tag exists and get its text.

NOTES:

- The code above supposes you use doctrine for handling your database connection. If otherwise just modify the code properly.
- You should use [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/index.html) to generate routes in javascript instead of hardcoding them as in my example. That's where the option expose = true is used in my route configuration.
- You will have to check again if the tag exists in your controller where you handle the form submission, otherwise you will get a doctrine error for duplicate insertion when trying to persist an already existing tag.
- Of course you will have to change somewhat my code, especially if you don't use jQuery.